# What is the fastest SiC MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet, rf

I would like to know what is the fastest SiC FET greater than or equal to 10A in a TO-247-3 package.
Currently I am using a C2M0280120D. My switching speed is 7 MHz. I want to know if there is a faster FET.
Maybe the C3M0280090D would be better?

So, if I understand correctly, what I should be looking for to determine the speed of switching should be:
Lower RDS on.
Lower input capacitance.
Lower rise time? Turn on delay time?

Is that the idea?

Comment: I have here some C4N2020E's for sale, they're the fastest you can buy. Yep they're **very** expensive. You want them? Of course I am **joking**. Instead of asking for "the fastest" you should determine **what you need**. Yes, that is difficult and requires thinking and calculations. You might want to make a simulation model of how you're using the SiC FET, the load etc. Even if you'd have the world's fastest FET does not mean that that FET is the best solution. Indeed Rdson might be more important, it depends on your usage case.

Comment: What is your reactive load?  Ic=CdV/dt= 1nF* 10V/ns= 10 Amps (hah) What EMI can you handle? dI/dt=4100A/us ?

Comment: I am using it as an RF amplifier, so it is 50 ohm. I am not sure how to answer your question.

Comment: *I am using it as an RF amplifier* Do realize that that means that your're basically "on your own". I mean: these SiC FETs are designed to be **switching devices** and certainly **not designed to be used in an RF amplifier.** I am not saying that they cannot be used as such. They can (maybe) but it might be a challenge and you might get **very crappy** performance. For example: a lot of distortion. Can you explain why you're not using a FET that is **designed** to be used as an RF amplifier?

Comment: Because RF mosfets are many times more expensive. Right now I have four C2M0280120D and I'm getting 200 RF watts @ 3MHz, 40V, 7.1A. So 70% efficient is not too bad for my application. But when I try 7MHz it is around 50%.

Comment: Yes RF MOSFETs are more expensive. It is unclear to me what you're doing and how you're using this MOSFET. If you think that can be 'fixed" by choosing another MOSFET then you have a lot to learn. You should include your schematic. How you use a MOSFET can make or break performance.

Comment: 7MHz 10A ???  and you want SiC?

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 My opinion is that it's probably possible, but difficult to achieve those specifications in a hard-switched power module (efficiency? who knows...). I've looked at SiC MOSFETs for class E/F applications, but none of the modes that I want to use are constant envelope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious first disclaimer is that you're using these devices in ways that they are not intended, YMMV. That being said, here is how you might compare devices. I think it will probably work well for non-linear amplifier types (class C, E, F), but linearity will be hard. Harmonics are also tricky as well - I've had hard-switching SiC MOSFET circuits with significant frequency components above 200 MHz.

1. The internal gate resistance on SiC MOSFETs is relatively high. Check this property on the datasheet. Some manufacturers have lower resistances. Using C*iss* and R*gate*, you can get a first order estimate of how much your input signal will be attenuated.
2. The low output capacitance of SiC is only really an advantage if you're using them at significant fraction of their rated voltage.
3. The TO-247-3 is the *worst* package for a SiC MOSFET. Look for 4-leaded TO-247 packages, or SMT footprints with a Kelvin source connection.
4. On the topic of packages, your layout is *very* important. The Crss of SiC MOSFETs is high, so if you aren't careful the device will turn itself on/off. This will look like oscillations on the switching edge.
5. Ids max isn't the most useful metric for comparing, look at C*oss* times R*dson* at your expected current and expected bus voltage.
6. SiC MOSFETs need to be driven all the way to the full specified Vgs to get the advertised R*dson*, and they also don't really like negative Vgs. You might be seeing issues getting a large enough Vgs on the device turn it on hard. Since the limits on gate voltage are asymmetric, it can also be difficult to turn the device *off*.